# How to fetch all the fields from ServiceFeatureTable in arcgis

Tags: arcgis

I am using arcgis library 100.0.0 in android for displaying maps and information inside map.

I am using the following code to populate a ServiceFeaturetable using URL provided by arcGis. I am able to load the feature layer successfully into the mapview. I have written code that listens to the click on the symbol on the map, so that I can get some information about the specific feature on the map. I am able to get the specific feature OnClick.

Upon investigating the GetAttributes() result of the specific feature, I realize that it is not having all the fields. After investigating on internet, I found that the FeatureTable.QueryFeaturesAsync could be used to get all the fields of the feature. Even though I have written the code to get all the fields, I do not know how I link this result with the feature layer, so that the feature has all the fields that I require. Here is the code

```
final ServiceFeatureTable serviceFeatureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable("some URL");



        ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult>  queryresult =  serviceFeatureTable.queryFeaturesAsync(null, ServiceFeatureTable.QueryFeatureFields.LOAD_ALL);


        // create the feature layer using the service feature table
        final FeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(serviceFeatureTable);

        featureLayer.setSelectionColor(Color.YELLOW);
        featureLayer.setSelectionWidth(10);

        // add the layer to the map
        mapView.getMap().getOperationalLayers().add(featureLayer);

        // set an on touch listener to listen for click events
        mapView.setOnTouchListener(new DefaultMapViewOnTouchListener(getContext(), mapView) {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                // get the point that was clicked and convert it to a point in map coordinates
                Point clickPoint = mMapView.screenToLocation(new android.graphics.Point(Math.round(e.getX()), Math.round(e.getY())));
                int tolerance = 10;
                double mapTolerance = tolerance * mMapView.getUnitsPerDensityIndependentPixel();
                // create objects required to do a selection with a query

                Envelope envelope = new Envelope(clickPoint.getX() - mapTolerance, clickPoint.getY() - mapTolerance, clickPoint.getX() + mapTolerance, clickPoint.getY() + mapTolerance, mapView.getMap().getSpatialReference());
                QueryParameters query = new QueryParameters();

                query.setGeometry(envelope);


                // call select features
                final ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> future = featureLayer.selectFeaturesAsync(query, FeatureLayer.SelectionMode.NEW);

                // add done loading listener to fire when the selection returns
                future.addDoneListener(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            //call get on the future to get the result
                            FeatureQueryResult result = future.get();
                            // create an Iterator
                            Iterator<Feature> iterator = result.iterator();
                            Feature feature;
                            // cycle through selections
                            int counter = 0;
                            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                                feature = iterator.next();
                                counter++;
                                String name = feature.getAttributes().get(Constants.FIELD_NAME).toString();
                                Log.d(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "Selection #: " + counter + " Table name: " + feature.getFeatureTable().getTableName());
                            }
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), counter + " features selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "Select feature failed: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
                return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your code

from

```
final ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> future = featureLayer.selectFeaturesAsync(query, FeatureLayer.SelectionMode.NEW);
```

to

```
final ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> future = serviceFeatureTable.queryFeaturesAsync(query, ServiceFeatureTable.QueryFeatureFields.LOAD_ALL);
```

It works for me!